# Issue with model after import from Sketchup via Sketchup plugin

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: view on Sketchup model in Blender how the model]

It looks so bad, after import into Blender from SketchUp. Import done via Sketchup plugin from Sketchup models import. Callada does not work at all.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Since you're using a third-party addon to import a model created in an external program you should ask in a Sketchup forum! In any case we don't know what your model is supposed to look like so how can we give advice?

Comment: Hi. I would add that you might possibly get some help here if your question were edited to ask regarding your problem importing as Collada (.dae), since that is a Blender supplied import method. You say that it doesn't work at all. Maybe it has to do with some export setting you are, or are not, using in Sketchup. Also, see what, if any, Blender import options might be checked. And, as @JohnEason said, you are probably better off looking around on Sketchup's forum.